# C Error: Expected declaration or statement at end of input in c

Tags: c, data-structures

I am not missing any } or ; then why am i getting this error?
The actual error says" Expected declaration or statement at the end of input".

```
bool search(struct bstnode* root,int data) {
    if(root == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    else if(root->data == data) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(data <= root->data) {
        return Search(root->left,data);
    }
    else { 
        return Search(root->right,data);
    }
}//getting error at this point
```

Full Code of the question...for Binary Search Tree, getting error in search function(below). Thanks in Advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define BOOL bool

struct bstnode{
int data;
struct bstnode* left;
struct bstnode* right;
};
struct bstnode* insert(struct bstnode* root,int data);
//struct bstnode* root=NULL;
bool Search(struct bstnode* root,int data);

int main()
{
struct bstnode* root = NULL;
root = Insert(root,15);
root = Insert(root,10);
root = Insert(root,20);
root = Insert(root,25);
root = Insert(root,8);
root = Insert(root,12);

int number;
printf("Enter number be searched\n");
scanf("%d",&number);
//If number is found, print "FOUND"
search(root,number);
if(search(root,number) == true) printf("Found\n");
else printf("Not Found\n");
 }

struct bstnode* getnewnode(int data)
{
struct bstnode* newnode=(struct bstnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct bstnode*));
newnode=(struct bstnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct bstnode*));
newnode->data=data;
newnode->left=NULL;//Initially Null, not pointing at anything
newnode->right=NULL;//Initially NULL, not pointing at anything
return newnode; //Return address of New Node
}

struct bstnode* insert(struct bstnode* root,int data) {
{
if(root==NULL)//condition 1, tree is empty.
{
root=getnewnode(data);//get address of newNode in root
}

else if(data<= root->data)
{
root->left=insert(root->left,data);

}
else
{
root->right=insert(root->right,data);
}
return root;
}

bool search(struct bstnode* root,int data) {

if(root == NULL) {
return false;
}
else if(root->data == data) {
return true;
}
else if(data <= root->data) {
return Search(root->left,data);
}
else
{
return Search(root->right,data);
}
}//getting error here.
```

Comment: Copy the exact error into the question. No paraphrasing.

Comment: And is this the last function in the file?

Comment: yeah, last function. Error says: "Expected declaration or statement at end of input."

Comment: Hi! Can you be a little more specific on the error that you are getting?

Comment: Can you paste your full program here

Comment: Add a newline after the function

Comment: At first glance there is nothing wrong with this code. However, compilers can get confused from errors earlier on. Most likely a closing brace `}` is missing earlier in the source file or in an included header file.

Comment: Is that the actual code or autocorrect putting an uppercase on Search?

Comment: You have `2` open `{` at `insert` function top.

Comment: If you indented your code properly you would probably not have this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved your syntactical errors in your code. You have added `{` twice top of `insert()` function. Also, typo mistake on `search()` and `insert()` function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define BOOL bool

struct bstnode
{
    int data;
    struct bstnode* left;
    struct bstnode* right;
};
struct bstnode* insert(struct bstnode* root,int data);
//struct bstnode* root=NULL;
bool search(struct bstnode* root,int data);

int main()
{
    struct bstnode* root = NULL;
    root = insert(root,15);
    root = insert(root,10);
    root = insert(root,20);
    root = insert(root,25);
    root = insert(root,8);
    root = insert(root,12);

    int number;
    printf("Enter number be searched\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    //If number is found, print "FOUND"
    search(root,number);
    if(search(root,number) == true) printf("Found\n");
    else printf("Not Found\n");
}

struct bstnode* getnewnode(int data)
{
    struct bstnode* newnode=(struct bstnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct bstnode*));
    newnode=(struct bstnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct bstnode*));
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->left=NULL;//Initially Null, not pointing at anything
    newnode->right=NULL;//Initially NULL, not pointing at anything
    return newnode; //Return address of New Node
}

struct bstnode* insert(struct bstnode* root,int data) {

    if(root==NULL)//condition 1, tree is empty.
    {
        root=getnewnode(data);//get address of newNode in root
    }

    else if(data<= root->data)
    {
        root->left=insert(root->left,data);

    }
    else
    {
        root->right=insert(root->right,data);
    }
    return root;
}

bool search(struct bstnode* root,int data) {

    if(root == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    else if(root->data == data) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(data <= root->data) {
        return search(root->left,data);
    }
    else
    {
        return search(root->right,data);
    }
}
```